# Viewing the symbol table

Tags: c#, symbol-table

I use VS Code to write programs.I want to view the symbol table for a particular program. can anyone tell me how to access the symbol table in VS or VS Code or any other place where it is readable?

Comment: The compiler can output the symbol table (map) as a text file.  Different version of VS has the option in different places.

Comment: @jdweng can you elaborate the procedure for doing that

Comment: @jdweng: for C and C++, sure. The C# compiler has no such option. (Nor does it have any need of it; .NET assemblies contain their own metadata.)

Comment: You may be looking for an IL inspector: `ildasm`, `ilspy`, take your pick. This is not the exact same thing as the symbol table (which is a structure entirely internal to the compiler itself) but .NET assemblies contain metadata on all the types and their members, which I suspect is what you're after.

Comment: @JeroenMostert is .pdb file of any help in this case?

Comment: Depends on what you need. .NET .pdb files don't duplicate the metadata already in the assembly, so they just add source file, line number and local variable data. (Disclaimer: it doesn't help that there's multiple different formats all covered by the same extension -- [portable PDBs](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/diagnostics/portable_pdb.md) are the latest thing.) In general, reading .pdb files is trickier than reading the assembly metadata.

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbols